# Scheduling an Apex Job through the ui

Tags: scheduled-apex

I am not sure if my memory is failing me, but I was sure there was a way to schedule an Apex Job through the Salesforce UI.

The documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) only makes mention of using the cron syntax. and [here](http://na10.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/data_monitoring_jobs.htm) only describes monitoring existing jobs.

Has this feature been removed, or am I missing something really obvious.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was, can't quite remember the navigation path though. Have a feeling it was a button on the Develop > Classes screen?

Comment: From what I recall, the scheduling UI is significantly more restrictive on when your job runs than leveraging the CRON syntax in the developer console (if you find that you can't get your schedule exactly as you want).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWelburn you're right it is, mandatory end date??? This question was on behalf of a non technical user, who could never have understood the cron syntax :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Setup -> Develop -> Classes

You will see a "Schedule Apex" button.  You can set up the timing from there.

[image: Schedule Apex Image]

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks Derek, I probably looked everywhere else

Answer (score 6):

Just checked - there is a Schedule Apex Button on the Setup > Develop > Classes screen, although I struggled to find a mention of it in the Scheduled Apex doc.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:
Implement the Schedulable interface in an Apex class that instantiates the class you want to schedule.
Step 2: From Setup, click Develop | Apex Classes and click Schedule Apex.

for more information pls refer:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_schedule_batch_apex.htm&language=en_US